# Count hidden elements regardless of parent visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden

I need to count hidden elements regardless of parent visibility.

I have this code:

```
<div id="parent-1">    
    <div class="item" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="item" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>

<script>
   var hidden_items = $('#parent-1').find('.item:hidden').length;
   console.log (hidden_items);
</script>
```

In this example I get **3** items, so is correct.

But with this code:

```
<div id="parent-2" style="display: none;">    
    <div class="item" style="display: none;">
    <div class="item" style="display: none;">
    <div class="item">
    <div class="item" style="display: none;">
</div>

<script>
   var hidden_items = $('#parent-2').find('.item:hidden').length;
   console.log (hidden_items);
</script>
```

I get **4** elements! because parent is a hidden element, but I need to get 3.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your case `$('#parent-2 > .item[style]').length`

Comment: I need to check if hidden / not hidden, not whether it has style or not

Comment: Could be, but you haven't specified it in your question above. If those items have no styles by default and you change them using jQuery, than what I posted above is sufficient. If you are changing classes, than you should include `css` tag also. Whatever, you were not accurate enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter function to filter out elements that have display property set as none:

```
var hidden_items = $('#parent-2 .item').filter(function(){
 return $(this).css('display') == "none"
}).length;
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
$(function(){
var hidden_items = $('#parent-2 .item').filter(function(){
 return $(this).css('display') == "none"
 
 }).length;
 alert (hidden_items);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent-2" style="display: none;">    
    <div class="item" style="display: none;">
    <div class="item" style="display: none;">
    <div class="item">
    <div class="item" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to find out who down votes with out reason?

Comment: @guradio: You can not. JohnSkeet has answered here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers

Comment: that is so sad..the power of downvote should be given to responsible people

Comment: @guradio: seriously.

Comment: Hello Kurtko please can try my code ? I just want to confirm that its work or not ?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar how would it be to count the visible elements? `filter(function(){return $(this).css('display') == "visible"})` not works

Comment: I think just put filter(function(){return $(this).css('display') != "none"}) it will help.

Comment: I answer myself: `filter(function(){return $(this).css('display') != "none"})`

Answer (score 1):

That is because, When a parent element is hidden the children elements of it will also be hidden. That is the natural behavior. If you still want to get the elements regardless of its parent display property then use `.filter` with its `callBack` function.

```
var hidden_items = $('#parent-2 .item').filter(function(){
 return this.style.display == "none"
}).length;
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lt68n7b/)

Comment: Even this is correct. downvote like this is  annoying